# Graph with elements hierarchy in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, graph

I need make graph in graphic framework Qt. I use QGraphicView and QGraphicScene and make my graph by hand (add Recangles, late add line to display hierarchy of single elements). For you to get an idea, picture, what I think:

[image]

And my supervisor tell me, that it is inefective. Somebody had to do something similar before me. So I must look for some library or framework in Qt, which support graph like mine (see above) and support mouse tracking, because after click I need do some operation.

So I searched on Google for few days and only thing I find is QTreeView. It is what I need, but it's for directory structure and that's not what I imagined.

Please, know somebody something like QTreeView, but in graphical adaptation? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use delegates with QTreeView to customize like you want (color rectalngles): http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes

Comment: Thanks I'll try this way, if it will be more effective than my drawing ractangles in graphicview.